# Expression tree for Joined Tables in where-clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I joined two tables Collection and Pictures and created this class:

```
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class CollectionNPictures
    {
        public Collection Collection { get; set; }
        public Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created a query:

```
var SQL = from collection in _context.Collection
          join pictures in _context.Pictures
          on collection.Nummer equals pictures.Nummer
          select new CollectionNPictures { Collection = collection, Pictures = pictures };
```

I want to create a dynamic where-clause (like loop over predicate = predicate.And(c=> c.Collection.columnName.Contains(searchValues)))

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you need a dynamic where in the first place? What is the use case here?

Comment: The table Collection contains a lot of columns, more than 50 I guess. So the code with the where-clauses became really big and not every where-clause was always necessery. And because there were some patterns for most of the where-clauses. I reduced the code by 2/3 by creating a few expression trees

Comment: And because I had to decide which type and method exactly to use, I created less failures

Comment: Are you saying that the caller where the many where clauses were is fully hardcoded (i.e. the column names and values it needs to search are all fixed)? Would you mind updating your post with a sample of what the caller looks like without the custom dynamic expressions?

Comment: Sry for the late reply, right now the names are fully fixed. I work on it, to make it fully generic. I guess it will run faster than. When I made it I will post it. But propably someone else will be faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<CollectionNPictures>();
predicate = predicate.And(GenericPredicates.CreatePredicateStringContainsJoin("Collection", "Ort", Orte));

public static Expression<Func<CollectionNPictures, bool>> CreatePredicateStringContainsJoin(string table, string columnName, ICollection<string> searchValues)
{
    var predicateloc = PredicateBuilder.New<CollectionNPictures>();
    var eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CollectionNPictures), "c");
    var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    if(method is null)
        return predicateloc;

    foreach (string searchValue in searchValues)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
        {
            var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(eParam, table), columnName), method, Expression.Constant(searchValue));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<CollectionNPictures, bool>>(call, eParam);
            predicateloc = predicateloc.Or(lambda);
        }
    }

    return predicateloc;

}
SQL = SammlungSQL.Where(predicate);
```